# Why was Captain Steven "Steve" Hiller denied by NASA?

Tags: plot-explanation, independence-day

One of plots in ***Independence Day*** has United States Marine Cpt. Steven "Steve" Hiller wanting to become an Astronaut. It's part of his motivation in life. One scene prior to the apocalypse has him receive a letter from NASA rejecting his application.

Why was he rejected by NASA?

Comment: *"Steve, maybe when they asked about 'plans for first contact' you should **not** have replied 'punch them out & issue witty but sarcastic greeting!'."*

Comment: *quora!* https://www.quora.com/In-Independence-Day-why-does-Captain-Hiller-Will-Smiths-character-get-rejected-by-NASA-as-an-astronaut-candidate-given-what-a-good-pilot-he-is has some answers - TLDR: maybe stripper girlfriend, maybe his behaviour, but not certain as movie didn't state it

Answer (score 5):

His buddy explained earlier that although he respects Steve's girlfriend Jasmine, NASA is never going to accept Steve Hiller if he's dating (or married to) a stripper, which is what Jasmine does for a living.